# Integer coordinate set of points that is a member of sphere surface

Tags: geometry, diophantine-equations

I have a graphic application to develop which involve many spheres. I should determine then on run time.

Supposing that I have a sphere of radius r, how can I determine the sub set of the sphere surface points that are integer?

E.g., $r = 10$ I can have $(10,0,0), (8,6,0),$ etc.

(Obs.: I really think this is not a programming question, that's why I not posted In stack overflow. If I am wrong, please fell free to warn me that :)

Pedro

Comment: You could just check the integer "grid" the sphere is in by using the formula of the sphere to see which points are on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: Ok, thats a alternative. But it results in a solution O(n³), which I am trying to avoid...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/95/three.sq)?

Comment: @PedroDusso by solving it for the third coordinate and only looking at points who have certain distance to the center you can easily make it quite faster than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

Comment: See [this](http://www.dm.unito.it/~cerruti/ntlab2007/3squares-elementary.pdf) as well.

Comment: Obviously, there are no solutions if $r^2$ is not an integer. Are you assuming that $r$ is an integer?

Comment: See http://projecteuler.net/problem=360

Answer (score 1):

You could use Euclid's formula:
For $m > n, a = m^2 - n^2, b = 2mn, c = m^2 + n^2$
are solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Comment: The question's about spheres, not circles.

Comment: And then there is the Gauss-Legendre theorem that an integer is the sum of three integer squares if and only if it is not of the form $4^m(8n+7)$.